# Hilbert function of a primary ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals, hilbert-polynomial

I'm reading Geramita's lectures on fat points, but I found a passage a bit confusing. (I'll post the reference as soon as I'll find the link).
I read that a fat point (of order $t$, defined by the ${p}$-primary ideal $p^t$) in $\mathbb{P}^n$ behaves like $\binom{n+t-1}{n}$ distinct points (in the sense of the Hilbert function).

In order to prove this, the paper states that $$ H(S/p^t,s) =  \binom{n+t-1}{n} $$
if $s\geq t$, with $S=k[x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.

To prove this observation, they observe that $ F \in p^{t+1}$ $\iff$ all the partial derivatives of order $\leq t$, vanish at $P$ (the point defined by the ideal).

But I can't understand why $H(S/p^t)$ is equal to that binomial coefficient, I mean it should be equal to 
$$H(R/p^t,s)=\dim_k R_s-\dim_k (p^t)_s=\binom{n+s}{s}-\dim_k (p^t)_s$$
and I can't find an easy formula for the second dimension, I guess it involves some combinatoric tool I can't see.
Any help would be much appreciate.

Comment: If someone is interested this is the link ti the paper                https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www3.nd.edu/~stolz/Math70330(F2008)/Geramita.pdf&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwi6zs7_8ITbAhVHShQKHZyaBRwQFggNMAA&usg=AOvVaw2XtpLLVhV76fSuj0wIT9-L

Comment: Where is the claim/theorem in the note?

Comment: at the bottom of page 4, but in the last days I figured out why it works. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the reply.